# Decode char UTF8 escapes in Boost Spirit

Tags: c++, utf-8, escaping, boost-spirit, urldecode

**question asked:** [Spirit-general list](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/ascii-to-unicode-td4023504.html)

<sub>Hello all,</sub>

I'm not sure if my subject is correct, but the testcode will probably show
what I want to achieve.

I'm trying to parse things like:

- '%40' to '@'
- '%3C' to '<'

I have a minimal testcase below. I don't understand why
this doesn't work. It's probably me making a mistake but I don't see it.

Using:
Compiler: gcc 4.6
Boost: current trunk

I use the following compile line:

```
g++ -o main -L/usr/src/boost-trunk/stage/lib -I/usr/src/boost-trunk -g -Werror -Wall -std=c++0x -DBOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3 main.cpp
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define BOOST_SPIRIT_UNICODE

#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp>

typedef boost::uint32_t uchar; // Unicode codepoint

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // Input
    std::string input = "%3C";
    std::string::const_iterator begin = input.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = input.end();

    using qi::xdigit;
    using qi::_1;
    using qi::_2;
    using qi::_val;

    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, uchar()> pchar =
        ('%' > xdigit > xdigit) [_val = (_1 << 4) + _2];

    std::string result;
    bool r = qi::parse(begin, end, pchar, result);
    if (r && begin == end) {
        std::cout << "Output:   " << result << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Expected: < (LESS-THAN SIGN)" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Error" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Regards,

Matthijs Möhlmann

Answer (score 2):

`qi::xdigit` does not do what you think it does: it returns the raw character (i.e. `'0'`, not `0x00`).

You could leverage [`qi::uint_parser`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/uint.html) to your advantage, making your parse much simpler as a bonus:

```
typedef qi::uint_parser<uchar, 16, 2, 2> xuchar;
```

- no need to rely on phoenix (making it work on older versions of Boost)
- get both characters in one go (otherwise, you might have needed to add copious casting to prevent integer sign extensions)

Here is a fixed up sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define BOOST_SPIRIT_UNICODE

#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

typedef boost::uint32_t uchar; // Unicode codepoint

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

typedef qi::uint_parser<uchar, 16, 2, 2> xuchar;
const static xuchar xuchar_ = xuchar();


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // Input
    std::string input = "%3C";
    std::string::const_iterator begin = input.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = input.end();

    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, uchar()> pchar = '%' > xuchar_;

    uchar result;
    bool r = qi::parse(begin, end, pchar, result);

    if (r && begin == end) {
        std::cout << "Output:   " << result << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Expected: < (LESS-THAN SIGN)" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Error" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Output:   60
Expected: < (LESS-THAN SIGN)
```

'<' is indeed ASCII 60